# ¿como aumentar los dias de un input date sin contar los domingos?

Tags: javascript, html5, date

Tengo un input date donde pongo una fecha y otro input date donde aparece N dias despues del dia que llene en el primer input date, pero quiero los N dias no cuenten a los domingos.

Lo que hice hasta ahora que es facil es aumentar los N dias pero contando con domingo

CODIGO

```js
function myFunction() {
               
       document.getElementById("myDate1").value=document.getElementById("myDate").value;
       document.getElementById("myDate1").stepUp(5);
    }
```

```html
    Date: <input type="date" id="myDate" >
    
    <p>Click the button to increment the value of the date field by 5 days (each time you click).</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <input type="date" id="myDate1" >
    
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> The stepUp() method is not supported by Internet Explorer.</p>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> input elements with type="date" do not show as any date field/calendar in Firefox or in IE 11 and earlier versions.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar una librería llamada [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) que te facilita el trabajo con fechas, usar el método [day()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) que te proporciona dicha librería para conocer que día de la semana es y usar un condicional para filtrar según sea necesario.

A continuación te expongo un ejemplo de su uso:

```js
var campoFecha = document.getElementById("fecha");
var campoDiaSemana = document.getElementById("dia-semana");

campoFecha.value = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

campoFecha.addEventListener("input", function() {
  var fecha = moment(campoFecha.value);
  campoDiaSemana.value = fecha.day();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Trabajando fechas con moments</title>
        <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="fecha">Edita este campo</label>
        <input type="date" id="fecha">
        <br>
        <label for="fecha">Dia de la semana</label>
        <input id="dia-semana" disabled>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes un ejemplo en JS.

```js
var startDate = "9-DEC-2011";
startDate = new Date(startDate.replace(/-/g, "/"));
var endDate = "", noOfDaysToAdd = 13, count = 0;
while(count < noOfDaysToAdd){
    endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1));
    if(endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6){
       //Date.getDay() gives weekday starting from 0(Sunday) to 6(Saturday)
       count++;
    }
}
alert(endDate);//You can format this date as per your requirement
```

el [Demo del JS](http://jsfiddle.net/HaJpQ/)

Comment: ¿podrías por favor poner un poco más de esmero al responder una pregunta, agregando una descripción además del código?